# how to fix the problem of zero bytes file getting generated when using pg_dump through cron job for regular backup?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, cron, pg-dump

while taking a backup of Postgres database using the pg_dump tool in a shell script,
if I schedule the script in cron then a backup file of 0 bytes gets generated.

On generating error logs using 2>&1 in cron job, the following error file gets generated :

> /home/sample_bkp.sh: 10: /home/sample_bkp.sh: -d: not found
>   backup directory: /home/bkp/2019_06_24_17_15
>   creating backup of phhc database
>   pg_dump: server version: 9.2.4; pg_dump version: 9.1.24
>   pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
>   pg_dump: *** aborted because of error

Answer (score 1):

The key message seems to be:

```
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

That means that the version of `pg_dump` is older than the version of the database you are trying to backup.

Since you say that it only happens from `cron`, something in the environment must cause a wrong `pg_dump` to be chosen.

The problem is made more difficult because of the Ubuntu distribution's wrapper scripts that then call the actual executable.

One simple attempt would be to uninstall old PostgreSQL versions that you do not use any more.

Another idea would be to call `pg_dump` with an absolute path to the correct executable.